Teamviewer Quicksupport influences Android Applications User Interface
We recently discovered that with the latest TeamViewer QuickSupport version, our Android app's user interface malfunctions as soon as we connect to QuickSupport. The device has a built-in QR and barcode scanner that typically scans and presses enter afterward. The app only seems to work properly when there is no active connection and the QuickSupport app is not running in the background, which is very odd. Is there a reason why QuickSupport would significantly affect the UI of another app?
We logged the whole process it seems to store the shared preferences and loads it without problem.
But changing the UI according to that setting doesnt work.
